# How to measure cache memory of Spring Boot Cacheable?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-data-jpa

We are adding Caching to spring boot application as per the following link:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-caching

How to view or measure cache memory used in the spring boot application ?

Comment: have you tried anything or you just added cache in your application and you want to calculate the size of the cache

Comment: Which cache implementation have you used

Comment: I just used @Cacheable

Comment: it depends on the CacheProvider: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-caching-provider

Comment: @MeikoRachimow Now I am using Caffeine cache provider. How to measure now ?